# formatting of files before indexing into solr server

Tags: solr, tokenize

I'm using the Solr server to provide search capability for a tool. I wanted to know if there is a facility provided by solr that will allow me to format some files before they are indexed ? more specifically i have a plain text file with a lot of data ! i want to convert them to an xml format before i index the xml file . eg

```
    some data! some more data : more values
```

i want to convert this sample line to something like

```
    <field 1>sample data </field 1>
    <field 2> some more data </field 2>  
    <field 3> more values  </field 3>
```

does solr provide a facility for this type of transformation before iindexing a file using solr cell. does it provie any classes or interfaces that i can implement in my java application ??

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you pushing data into Solr or can you pull it from the source by Solr?

If you are pushing into Solr, then you have to use [Update Request Processor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor). However, I am not aware of any that will split data into multiple fields. You may need to write one yourself.

If you are pulling from the source using DataImportHandler, it has a built-in support for splitting content into multiple fields using [RegexTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#RegexTransformer).

Both Request Processor and DIH support JavaScript (and possibly other Java script languages) transformers, so you can also write your own script to split the data in whatever way you want.

Some of this is starting with version 4 of Solr though. That's a requirement to keep in mind.

Comment: well the actual problem is this ..i have a large plain text file with a lot of data. consider a sample format : 

`somedatestamp someType someValue
somedatestamp someType someValue
somedatestamp someType someValue
`
so i have around a 1000 lines like these .. i would like to query this file to return values between two datestamps. i thought if i could tokenize it it would be easier to query on the attribute instead of on the large string. Is there a way to do this ??

Comment: If you need to return the 'values' then you don't want those 'values' in the same document. Then you actual document contains that value and relevant date. I would look at DataImportHandler and nested entities where content of the inner entity comes from the processed content of the external entity. Then, external entity reads your file and splits it into chunks somehow. That's a start, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom [`Index Handler`](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers) or a [`SolrRequestHandler`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/index.html)